# Comic book conversion

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have two small structs (might change to classes later) that get loaded into Generic lists. The loading of the lists is what I'm asking about. Can it be done better or more object-oriented?

You'll notice I'm using MS Enterprise library for data access to a SqlCe database.

I'm just looking for some opinions on this code. Is there a more efficient way to do what I've written so far? My goal is to make the code as efficient and small as possible while still being maintainable and expandable.

```
 public class ConversionUtility
{

    private List<ComicBook> _books;
    private List<ComicPublisher> _publishers;

    private void Load()
    {
        try
        {
            _books = GetBooks();
            _publishers = GetPublishers();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void PerformConversion()
    {
        Load();

       //still working on this

    }


    private List<ComicPublisher> GetPublishers()
    {
        List<ComicPublisher> tmp = new List<ComicPublisher>();

        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("CeConnectionString");

        IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, "SELECT * FROM Publisher");

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            tmp.Add(new ComicPublisher { Id = (int)rdr["PublisherId"], Name = rdr["PublisherName"].ToString() });
        }
        return tmp;

    }

    private List<ComicBook> GetBooks()
    {
        List<ComicBook> tmp = new List<ComicBook>();

        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("CeConnectionString");

        IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, "SELECT * FROM Book");

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            tmp.Add(new ComicBook { Id = (int)rdr["BookId"], Title = rdr["Title"].ToString(), Company = rdr["Company"].ToString() });
        }

        return tmp;

    }

}


public struct ComicPublisher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public struct ComicBook
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Dispose()` of your `IDisposable` type (`IDataReader`) with  a `using` block.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, this is small but it's not truly a project. This is just something I'm trying to put into habit. I'd like to have a consistent style in my coding :) The interface idea is excellent. I'm going to play with that some. Good call about closing the reader! I had it wrapped in a using statement but the runtime yelled at me. It was saying something about the Enterprise Library not liking it but I didn't pay a whole lot of attention at the time unfortunately. Overall, using a reader and creating the new instances of the classes for each record found looks good up there? Thanks so muc

Answer (score 4):

Firstly:

### Close your DataReaders!!!

Secondly:

You may want to consider abstracting boilerplate code like this:

```
  Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("CeConnectionString");
  IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, "SELECT * FROM Book");
```

Into some helper methods.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `struct`s to be immutable and to use `interface` types when available, so I have this (incorporating my comment to the question) to present:

```
public sealed class ConversionUtility
{
    private IList<ComicBook> _books;
    private IList<ComicPublisher> _publishers;

    public void PerformConversion()
    {
        this.Load();

        // still working on this
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        try
        {
            this._books = this.GetBooks();
            this._publishers = this.GetPublishers();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private IList<ComicPublisher> GetPublishers()
    {
        IList<ComicPublisher> tmp = new List<ComicPublisher>();

        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("CeConnectionString");

        using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, "SELECT * FROM Publisher"))
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                tmp.Add(new ComicPublisher((int)rdr["PublisherId"], rdr["PublisherName"].ToString()));
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    private IList<ComicBook> GetBooks()
    {
        IList<ComicBook> tmp = new List<ComicBook>();

        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("CeConnectionString");

        using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, "SELECT * FROM Book"))
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                tmp.Add(new ComicBook((int)rdr["BookId"], rdr["Title"].ToString(), rdr["Company"].ToString()));
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }
}

public struct ComicPublisher
{
    private readonly int id;
    private readonly string name;

    public ComicPublisher(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get { return this.id; } }
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
}

public struct ComicBook
{
    private readonly int id;
    private readonly string title;
    private readonly string company;

    public ComicBook(int id, string title, string company)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public int Id { get { return this.id; } }
    public string Title { get { return this.title; } }
    public string Company { get { return this.company; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this into a generic method. If you wanted to change your tables & classes to a consistent format then it would be very simple:

```
interface IThing
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    string DatabaseTableName {get;}
}

class GetThings<T> where T : IThing, new()
{
    private List<T> GetItems()
    {
        var t = new T();

        List<T> tmp = new List<T>();
        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("CeConnectionString");
        string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", t.DatabaseTableName);
        IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, query);

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            tmp.Add(new T { Id = (int)rdr["Id"], Name = rdr["Name"].ToString() });
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

and your classes need to implement the IThing interface.  If you don't want to use an interface then things will get messier, and reflection and property matching will be required.

Having said that, I don't believe it's worth writing generic classes to handle two structs.

Comment: And what effect would Little Bobby Tables have on this code? https://xkcd.com/327/